# Can I custom tab layout and theme in android?

Tags: android, tabs

I'm having a really hard time understanding how to use custom tabs in android. I don't want to just be able to set the text and stuff. How can I change the size, and the image, and all that. for example I want to change tab theme (Rounded corners instead of angular) OR create new theme e.g. hexagonal shape.

Almost, I wanna create a tab such as `File Expert 5.0.4`: 
[image]

I've googled and I can't find anything that makes sense

Comment: Hi Omid you got any solution for this.
I also stuck for the same.

Comment: @umesh I got what I should do. I could implement it with separated layout for each header of tabs. I try to set a time and write my solution. Hope it help you, too.